# IE9 and Windows 7 task bar integration

Tags: feature-request

I'm trying IE9 and I have pinned the SO site (well, questions tagged as PowerShell) to my Windows 7 Taskbar.  What I would really love to see and I don't know if this is possible, is some sort of a taskbar icon overlay indicating new questions posted since my last visit/refresh.  Ideally the icon overlay would indicate the number of new questions but that might not be possible.  Perhaps it might work like an IE RSS subscription and flag the icon when there is something new.  It is quite likely that this would require support from IE9. I think I'll also post a suggestion with Microsoft.

Just looking at the [IEBLog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106084404/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-available-for-download.aspx) and I see this comment:

*Sites can also program notifications when the user pins them in the task bar.*

So this looks like it is possible.  Unfortunately it looks like IE9 and this post editor aren't quite getting along.  :-(

**Update:** found this in a feature list for IE9:

*Icon overlays. Icon overlays are available on Windows 7 taskbar for pinned sites and provide an indication of personalized website specific status such as number of new messages.*

Comment: Jeff will probably tell you this himself, but there's no support for beta browsers.

Comment: Totally understandable.  Just wanted to get it queued up for when it is no longer beta. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that would have to be done via http://stackapps.com -- have you looked there?

I know there are Chrome add-ins that do what you're describing, for example.

Comment: I've written a few apps that do this myself.

Comment: I will upvote you because you are hurting for some more rep

Comment: No I haven't yet but I will look at it.

Comment: Even if you guys don't feel like leveraging the full IE9 taskbar API, can we at least get a higher resolution icon? Just requires adding it to the favicon (ideally 64x64). Jumplists and the whole she-bang would be great, but we can start small. :)

Comment: @sapph the problem is that favicon.ico is downloaded literally 500,000+ times per day, and I don't want to bloat it with 64+kb of data that will almost never be used. We need to find some way of leveraging http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png which is in the html source of every single page we serve..

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that this would be a cool feature to have, it will require IE9 specific programming, so I don't know if it's something we'll see. Here's some sample code that can accomplish this, taken from [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE9SiteSpecificBrowsersAndAddingYourOwnJumpListItemsToPinnedTabs.aspx):

```
//show
window.external.msSiteModeSetIconOverlay(iconUri, toolTip);

//hide an Overlay Icon:
window.external.msSiteModeClearIconOverlay();
```

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like this idea. The overlay can be added when a question you have open is updated, when a chat has new messages, or when a search has new results.